# Prove a function is differentiable

Tags: derivatives

In general (with a text) how can I justify that for example, the function:

$$\int_1^x\left((\frac{1}{t}) * e^u\right)\,dt = F(t)$$
$u = \frac{t^2+1}{t}.$

I can say it's because the function results of operations of continuous functions but that's not enough, isn't it?

NOTE: I'm studying Calculus I I know that in Calculus II we learn a formal process to prove this...

Comment: Don't you mean $F(x)$ rather than $F(t)$?  The expression on the left doesn't depend on $t$ at all, since it is integrated out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: By the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), the integral of a continuous function is differentiable.